# Angular JS promise evaluation

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

UPDATE: I dug a little deeper and found that angular deprecated [auto-unwrapping of promises](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577) following 1.2.0.

I understand that Angular JS will evaluate scope variables which are a promise and then update the controller's view when the promise is fulfilled.

My question is:

http://jsfiddle.net/dhruvkaran/Lv5vF/4/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController">
    {{foo}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

  myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "bar";
  });
</script>
```

works just fine, but,

http://jsfiddle.net/dhruvkaran/Lv5vF/5/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController">
    {{foo}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve("bar");
    $scope.foo = deferred.promise;
  });
</script>
```

does not.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the promise incorrectly. A promise is something that will be fulfilled sometime in the future as either resolved or rejected. Also: scope variables aren't necessarily a promise, so this may be where you are getting confused. To use the promise correctly, you need to add a callback using the "then" function of the promise:

```
myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope, $q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.resolve("bar");

  //Note: Promises are not normally resolved inline like above
  deferred.promise.then(function (data) {
     $scope.foo = data;
  });

});
```

Comment: In this case it won't help because promise is resolved before function is registered to handle it.

Comment: You can actually resolve a promise before any callbacks are registered with the promise. jsfiddle of OP's code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5vF/6/

Comment: Thanks guys! I dug a little deeper. Turns out angular [deprecated auto-unwrapping of promises](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577) following 1.2.0.